# toggleBreakpointsTargetFactory specified id is already registered

Tags: eclipse, node.js, debugging, windows-7, nodeclipse

Node.js debugging is not working, out of the box.

On a fresh install of eclipse Kepler SR1 Build id: 20130919-0819, on 64-bit Windows 7, I installed Nodeclipse and Enide 0.6 using the Eclipse Marketplace.

I created a new Node-Express project, in a new workspace.  In Project Explorer, I right-clicked on app.js and selected "Debug As --> Node Application".

The console shows:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe --debug-brk=5858 F:\workspace\test\app.js

but **node.exe died immediately** and a dialog popped up "Launching delegate...", followed by an error dialog: 'Launching STANDALONE_V8' has encountered a problem. *(I'm guessing that node.exe had already exited so there was no instance of V8 for the debugger to connect to.)*

The eclipse error log shows an Error:

> org.eclipse.debug.ui.toggleBreakpointsTargetFactory extension failed to load breakpoint toggle target because the specified id is already registered.  Specified ID is: org.chromium.debug.ui.ChromiumToggleBreakpointTargetFactory

This same sequence works flawlessly on a colleague's machine.  Where on my machine is this breakpoint target id registered, and how do I clear it? Or what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

This is issue #72

- Try first to update JDK to the latest 7.u40 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
- then if it is not solved, uninstall Nodeclipse core then install again
- Nodeclipse version doesn't matter as it was thought before, I saw this bug on 0.4 as well

Report of the issue solved by exact steps: 
https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/72#issuecomment-25942319

Try also Enide Studio https://sourceforge.net/projects/nodeclipse/files