# Running and debugging node project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, node.js, debugging, v8, nodeclipse

I want to run a node.js project locally and create a debugging session.
Normally, this would be accomplished by running "debug as" a node project in Eclipse.
However, when I run the debugging session, nothing seems to run locally. In other words, when I open a browser and point to localhost, nothing is running.

It says the "debugger listening on port 5858", but my application doesn't appear to be running via any port.

[image]

and when I try to debug it using the V8 debugger I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm no node expert, but i guess the following will solve your problem:
You have to start two programs in debug mode. Besides your remote debug start configuration, you also have to start a server in debug mode first. Your remote debug mode will then connect to it, when started.

Answer (score 0):

Nodeclipse sometimes has issue #72 when launching Node app.
(Exact reason is not clear as it is hard to reproduce once it is fixed.
This is Java version related issue)

See [toggleBreakpointsTargetFactory specified id is already registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689501/togglebreakpointstargetfactory-specified-id-is-already-registered) , and [node.js express app won't start (or debug) in Eclipse (Nodeclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877014/node-js-express-app-wont-start-or-debug-in-eclipse-nodeclipse?lq=1)

Create issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/) with exact environment specification.